# Maven not found in Netbeans

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, netbeans

Netbeans was installed using the ubuntu software manager.

The instructions on the netbeans website for setting up a maven project in netbeans are the following:

> 1. Choose File > New Project (Ctrl-Shift-N) to open the New Project wizard.
> 2. Select NetBeans Application from the Maven category:

But the maven category is not there on my installation.

Also on the website:

> 1. Select the Miscellaneous category in the Options window and click the Maven tab.

But there is no maven tab at all. What's the reason for maven not being there, and how can I get it working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the maven plugin inside Netbeans.

Go in the menu `Tools -> Plugins`

In the `Available plugins` section, select the Maven plugin from the Java SE category and install it. You can use the search box to find it easily.

Comment: Also, be sure the activate the maven plugin (Tools > Plugins > Installed)

Answer (score 1):

Install maven in ubuntu first using command

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

Comment: I've tried installing it this way and also with a .deb and neither have worked